# How to stop trying to retrieve rows if they do not exist?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

After looking into it this seems quite common but I didn't find an answer that was really appropriate for what I was looking for.

I have this method which will returns the first 5 rows. However, when the rows are empty it pops up with

> java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.

per empty row.

How would I stop this code trying to return results when there are no more rows?

```
public Appointment viewUpcomingAppointmentsDB(int i) throws SQLException {
    Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dBPath, dBUsername, dbPassword);
    Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
    Appointment ap1 = new Appointment();
    ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(
        "select a.AppointmentID, a.Time, a.Date, d.SName, p.SName from Appointment as a" +
        " Inner join Doctor as d on d.DoctorID = a.DoctorID Inner join Patient as p on " +
        "p.PatientNInsurance = a.PatientNInsurance where Date(a.date) >= DATE(NOW())  order by Date");

    int k = 0;
    while (k < rowsToRead) {
        myRs.next();
        k++;
    }

    ap1.setAppointmentID(myRs.getString("AppointmentID"));
    ap1.setDate(myRs.getString("Date"));
    ap1.setTime(myRs.getString("Time"));
    ap1.setPatientName(myRs.getString("p.SName"));
    ap1.setDoctorName(myRs.getString("d.SName"));

    myStmt.close();
    myConn.close();
    return ap1;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `next()` twice in the loop. **Don't.**

```
if (myRs.next()) {  // <-- Advances to the next row
    while (k < i) { // <-- What is this loop supposed to do?

    }
    myRs.next();    // <-- Advances to the next row, but that
                    //     row is never used. Delete this line.
    k++;
}
```

To retrieve *up to* `i` (bad name, use `rowsToRead` or something like that), use a combined `for` loop:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= i && myRs.next(); row++) {
    // process row here
}
```

That loop will exit after `i` rows, or when `ResultSet` exhausts all available rows, whichever comes first.

Comment: Don't (try to) post code in a comment. Edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (myRs.next() || k > i){
// do stuff with the current row
}
```

That loop will stop when there is no more row available in the resultSet or if you reached your limit i.

In your case you stop when you reach your i parameter, which can be bigger the actual number of row in your result set.

There are other issues in your code but that should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks!
Would you mind elaborating on the other issues? I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: It seems like i (now named rowsToRead) is the max row you want, then you should add that limit to the sql request ("limit " + rowsToRead).

Comment: Also, I don't understand the whole thing. You grab a bunch of rows, move to one (the ith) and just use it to return the Appointment. That's very bad for performance. See if whatever call that method can pass the id of the appointment you want to grab